# One maven dependency from mvnrepository.com resolves while the other does not

Tags: maven, swagger, openapi

**TLDR;**

*One depndency resolves and other does not. Can someone share how to debug it? or share some insight on what may be going on ?*

**Details:**

I created a new maven project to create `models` and `api` in typescript from `OpenApiV3.yaml` file.

In my project's `pom` file I added a plugin.

```
<profile>
        <id>typescript-angular</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.25</version>
```

`swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` does not resolve. I get error in build that it could not be found.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>typescript</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.0</version>
```

While `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` resolves. And does generate the objects.

[org.openapitools openapi-generator-maven-plugin 5.1.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openapitools/openapi-generator-maven-plugin/5.1.0)

[io.swagger.codegen.v3 swagger-codegen-maven-plugin 3.0.25](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.codegen.v3/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin/3.0.25)

We, in organization, do have a local `nexus` deployment but aparently this behavior is with same `pluginRepositories` in project's `pom` file. No change done to make it work for the other dependency.

```
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>maven-repository</id>
            <name>Maven Repository</name>
            <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>maven-central</id>
            <name>Maven Central</name>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Can someone share how to debug it? or share some insight on what may be going on ?

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ is not a consumeable maven repository .....

Comment: @khmarbaise Can you please elaborate a bit more? What else should I use then instead?

Comment: This one: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ is search for the artifacts like: https://search.maven.org/search?q=openapi-generator-maven-plugin and https://search.maven.org/search?q=swagger-codegen-maven-plugin